# Graphing a function with parameters (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have defined two functions, the second of which is a factory function.

```
 def bear(S,K):
     if S <= K:
         value = K
     elif K < S and S < 2*K:
         value = 2*K - S
     else:
         value = 0
     return value

 def makeBear(K)
     def bear1(x):
         return bear(x,K)
     return bear1
```

I am trying to produce a graph from a function of **`S`** when **`K`**`= 10` for `0 < S <` (some integer, `b`).

I also want to show it using my own **`y`** axis range, say **`[c, d]`**.

The examples I am trying to learn from do not have inequalities.

I am having a hard time relating their code to my own.

I have found that doing the following in console:

```
makeBear10 = makeBear(10)
makeBear10(0)
makeBear10(1)
makeBear10(2)
```

etc...

Gives me the points on the graph but I need a smaller, cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question here is. If you want a tutorial on how to plot x,y values, this question is too broad. You can google that. If the question is how to get the values, what about (example for 10 values) `x = range(10); y = [makeBear10(val) for val in x]`?

Comment: I basically need to plot a graph with x being 0-30 on the x-axis and makeBear10(x) on the y-axis. However you're answer has helped a great deal already. I just need the knowledge of how to set your own y-axis limits, in my case [-1, 11]. I assume its something close to plt.axis[-1,11] but I'll try and figure that one out

Answer (score 0):

- u can try linspace command

y = linspace(x1,x2) returns a row vector of 100 evenly spaced points between x1 and x2.

**example**

y = linspace(x1,x2,n) generates n points. The spacing between the points is (x2-x1)/(n-1).

linspace is similar to the colon operator, ":", but gives direct control over the number of points and always includes the endpoints. "lin" in the name "linspace" refers to generating linearly spaced values as opposed to the sibling function logspace, which generates logarithmically spaced values.

**Examples**

Vector of Evenly Spaced Numbers
Create a vector of 100 evenly spaced points in the interval [-5,5].

y = linspace(-5,5);
Vector with Specified Number of Values
Create a vector of 7 evenly spaced points in the interval [-5,5].

y1 = linspace(-5,5,7)
y1 =

-5.0000   -3.3333   -1.6667         0    1.6667    3.3333    5.0000